# How remove text wrap using vim text editor?

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to write a vim script for remove the text wrap, I am using the following code but it's doesn't provide exact output. eg \string{this indicate newline} if "this" appears in first line, "indicate" is in second line e.t.c then how I remove text wrap. Is it possible?

```
:%s/\\string{\zs\(\_[^}]*\)\ze}/\1/gec
```

#### Edit based on OP's comment:

```
for example (i/p): \string{1 <enterkey> 2 <enterkey> 3 <enterkey> 
4 <enterkey> 5 <enterkey>}. i need (o/p) \string{1 2 3 4 5}.
```

---

Before I have:

```
\string{1
2
3
4
5
}
```

After I want:

```
\string{1 2 3 4 5}
```

Before I have (new pattern):

```
\string{1 
{2} 
{3} 
4 
5}
```

After I want:

```
\string{1 {2} {3} 4 5}
```

Comment: can you pls give an example to show "before" and "after"?

Comment: for example (i/p): \string{1 <enterkey> 2 <enterkey> 3 <enterkey> 4 <enterkey> 5 <enterkey>}. i need (o/p) \string{1 2 3 4 5}.

Comment: I posted an answer for the requirement in your comment. next time pls add the code blocks in your question. I do the edit for you this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line does what you want:

```
%s/\\string{\_[^}]*/\=substitute(submatch(0),"\n",' ','g')/
```

it changes:

```
foobar
\string{1
2
3
4
5
}
foobar
```

into:

```
foobar
\string{1 2 3 4 5 }
foobar
```

Comment: great how it's possible ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to understand your question if you gave a longer example of text, and what you want to do with it.  If I understand correctly, you could like to remove the line wrap on lines that contain `\\string{this`.

You could use `:%g/\\string{this/j`. It executes the `j` command on every line matching the `\\string{this` pattern.

Input:

```
some text
\string{this
indicate}
more text
```

Turns into:

```
some text
\string{this indicate}
more text
```

Comment: Can you suggest any idea to select the contents inside the curly brace of \string{} and make it in a single line

Comment: Note that, the `:g//j` will do "join" only once. that is, only the first linebreak will be removed. And for `:g`, you don't need the `%` range.